# Having trouble with a custom print invoice button, the data from the record is being pulled to the form, however the company logo is being lost

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Long story short, I am having some difficulty with a button I have added to a Sales Order form. The button is added via a UE script at beforeLoad, which is tied to a function in a Client Script, which on click opens up a suitelet using an advanced pdf/html template which is populated by record data.

Normally, if you were to enter EDIT on the sales order, you can select the form, save it and then when you hit print, a new window tab will open with the populated template and a company logo. We have multiple subsidiaries and locations, the template uses if-logic to find the right logo. The button is a faster and more efficient solution, but there is a problem....

When you click the button, it will open a tab to download the suitelet, then when you open it you have the invoice with all of the data, but no logo. Sometimes I will get XML parser error also. The following bits are the suite script codes being used:

```
ProFormaButtonAdd.js ( user event script)

define([],

    function() {

function beforeLoad(context) {

    if(context.type != context.UserEventType.VIEW){

        return;

    };
context.form.addButton({

id: "custpage_pfi",

label: "Pro Forma Invoice",

functionName: "onButtonClick"

});

context.form.clientScriptModulePath = "SuiteScripts/ProFormaButtonOnClick.js";

}
return {

beforeLoad: beforeLoad

};

});



ProFormaButtonOnClick.js (client script)

define(['N/url', 'N/currentRecord'],

function(url, currentRecord) {

        function onButtonClick() {
var soRec = currentRecord.get();

var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({

scriptId: 'customscript_pro_forma_button_suitelet',

deploymentId: 'customdeploy_pro_forma_button_suitelet',

returnExternalUrl: false,

params: {

custom_id: soRec.id

},

});

window.open(suiteletUrl);

        };

        function pageInit(){}; // this needs to be here in order to use the client script
return {

onButtonClick: onButtonClick,

pageInit: pageInit

};

});



ProFormaButtonSuitelet.js (the suitelet script)

define(['N/render', 'N/record', 'N/xml'],

     function(render, record, xml){
function onRequest(context){

var custom_id = context.request.parameters.custom_id;

var pdfFileName = "Pro Forma Invoice";

var renderer = render.create();

var content = renderer.addRecord({ // this is a concern area

templateName: 'record',

record: record.load({

type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,

id: custom_id

})

});

renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("CUSTTMPL_131_4828307_SB1_226");

context.response.setHeader({

name: 'content-disposition',

value: 'inline; filename="' + pdfFileName + '_' + custom_id + '.pdf"'

});

context.response.writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf()); // this is a concern area

};

    return {
onRequest: onRequest

    };
});
```

I think it is safe to say that the issue lies in the suitelet script part, either in the data from the record being added into the renderer or with writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf()). I have had no luck in finding API docs for context.request and context.response syntax.

I have tried using other strategies for the suitelet script but with no luck. This is the closest I was able to get to. Another thought was maybe the advanced PDF/HTML template needs updated, however, as I mentioned earlier, everything works just fine when you change the form and print normally.

Another smaller issue I am having is when you hit the button it wants to download as "report.pdf", then the next one is report(1).pdf, then report(2).pdf and so on, but for now the company logo is a big concern.

Super appreciate any feedback I can get, you all rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: In NS 2021.1, `<img src="${companyInformation.logoUrl}">` works without handling '&' like below.

If you are using the url of the logo as image source in the template, try escaping the '&' in the url like this:

```
img src="${companyInformation.logoUrl?replace('&', '&amp;', 'r')}"
```

Comment: indeed...& break FreeMarker in APTs

Comment: Although this answer was not the immediate solution, we did find that our issue was within the template.  Thank you a ton for the help!

Comment: What solution did you find for this issue? hope you can remember.